# datagridview datasource is shared in multiple tabs created programmatically with usercontrol

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls

In a form I have a button that takes a `UserControl` adds it into new `Tab` and then adds this `Tab` into `TabControl`. In the `UserControl` there's a `DataGridView` that is inicialized in `UserControl.cs` file like this : `dataGridView.DataSource = MainWin.dataSet.DataTableVideo;`. Now the problem is that all of the pages share the `DataSource` and therefore if I change values in one DGV on page1, the values on page2 will be same. How can I separate them?

Comment: If there is just one data source the data __will and should__ be the same. you can have separate cursors but the data are always the same. If you want those to be independent you need copies not a shared DS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to anyone who might need it, as TaW said in the comment, on each page creation i make copy of the original not filled table like so:
`DataTable tablePositionText = MainWin.dataSet.DataTablePositionText.Copy();`
(note: it's important that it has `.Copy()` at the end to make it independent copy, otherwise it'd be a reference) and then work with this copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of the database data for each individual gridview in a business (view)model class. Then you can create an instance of that object for each grid, fill it with data from the database and assign it to the grid. After editing the data in a datagrid you can save the information stored in the object to the database. Do watch out with this interaction because which gridview will contain the leading information which is updated to the database...

Comment: I don't want to use database, for my purposes it's too much work, i'd have to create the database, connect to it and work with sql commands, that's why I used the DataSet in the first place.

Comment: The result is same, just create seperate objects of the class you want to use in the gridview.